# How to get started using aws_account_utils (ruby)?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

After searching around, I found this [aws_account_utils](https://github.com/intuit/aws_account_utils) which does exactly what I hope to achieve - programmatically create aws account.

Unfortunately as a total ruby noob, I have no idea how to start using it even after reading the README.md.

I suspect I'd need the following steps:

1. Create `create-account.rb`
2. Use the util in the code
3. Run `ruby create-account.rb`

How should the content of `create-account.rb` be like?

Please show me a template.
With that I should be able to start experimenting and hacking.

Any other steps I should do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan below is rough and must be supplemented.

1. Create `Gemfile` file. This file is needed to specify project dependencies (libraries)
2. Put this line into `Gemfile`

   ```
   gem 'aws_account_utils'
   ```
3. Run `bundle install` in your console / terminal
4. Create `create-account.rb` file with next code

   ```
   require 'aws_account_utils'

   aws_utils = AwsAccountUtils::AwsAccountUtils.new()

   details = { 'fullName'     => 'Herman Munster',
         'company'      => 'The Munsters',
         'addressLine1' => '1313 Mockingbird Lane',
         'city'         => 'Mockingbird Heights',
         'state'        => 'CA',
         'postalCode'   => '92000',
         'phoneNumber'  => '(800) 555-1212',
         'guess'        => 'Test Account' }

   resp = aws_utils.create_account(account_name: 'My Test Account 01',
                               account_email: 'adfefef@gmail.com',
                               account_password: 'foobar1212121',
                               account_details: details)
   ```

   This code uses `aws_account_utils` library. Documentation you can find [here](https://github.com/intuit/aws_account_utils#create_account).

After steps above you can run `ruby create-account.rb`.

Comment: Found that the following line is need ```aws_utils = AwsAccountUtils::AwsAccountUtils.new()```. Otherwise this helps to get started. Thanks!